# Vista, IIS7, Dynamic DNS & Netgear Issues

Tags: iis-7, windows-vista, netgear, ddns

I'm running Windows Vista Business and installed IIS 7 (I changed no settings in it, everything is on default). I have a domain and have setup Dynamic DNS for it with the host. I use a program provided by the host to update my server's IP. I have a Netgear router which I've configured the HTTP port (80) to forward to my server.

The problem is when I try to access the default website by typing in the domain's URL, all I get is a "Waiting for http://www.mydomain.com" message which eventually just returns:

> This webpage is not available.
>
> The webpage at
>   http://www.mydomain.com/ might be
>   temporarily down or it may have moved
>   permanently to a new web address.
>
> More information on this error Below
>   is the original error message
>
> Error 101 (net::`ERR_CONNECTION_RESET`):
>   Unknown error.

Here's what I tried:

1. I disabled the firewall on my server completely to see if it would resolve the issue, but no joy.
2. I've pinged the www.mydomain.com and it replies perfectly.
3. I've tried to flush the DNS (ipconfig /flushdns) via command prompt.
4. Accessing http://localhost on the server and http://myservername from other network computers works just fine.

I don't know what I'm missing, anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pinged www.mydomain.com did the reply come from the correct ip address, the one that's registered with the Dynamic DNS service?

Have you turned off the external web management feature of the Netgear router? Netgear routers allow web based (port 80) management connections from both the internal and external interfaces by default. This might be causing the problem as your attempt to browse the server might actually be going to the router instead, since ip address on the WAN interface on the router is the same ip address that's going to be registered with the Dynamic DNS service and ultimately NAT'ed through the router to the server for http traffic.

Comment: Yes to both. That's all in order.

Comment: When it fails, is it failing from a host on the same LAN? Have you tried from a host on another network?

Comment: Yes it's failing on the same LAN. I haven't tried to access it from a  different network, I'll do that in about an hour when I get to work and post the results. I also put IIS7 on another network computer and changed the port forwarding, same result though.

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the way the traffic is being routed through the router. The request originates from the same LAN as the server, but has to access it via the public ip address.

I have an IIS7 box and a Linksys router and have no problems accessing my web sites via their public ip addresses frm the Same LAN as the server.

From an internal host try to tracert to the public ip address of the server and see what the results are.

Comment: Hey Joe, I tried accessing the site from a different network and it it's working just fine! Is there anyway to resolve the problem of not being able to view the sites on my local network via it's public domain?

Comment: Well you could use the hosts file on your internal computers to point them to the internal ip address of the server but that's not an ideal solution. How about running a tracert from an internal computer to the public ip address of the server and see what path the traffic takes. This might give you some insight into what's happening. Also, take a look at all of the router settings and options and see if anything comes to light.